# Directory.GetFiles - how to get rid of the warning Possible null reference argument for parameter 'value'?

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

Possible null reference argument for parameter 'value' in 'bool string.Contains(string value)'

the warning is on this line on the existing

```
var link = Links.FirstOrDefault(linkItem => linkItem?.Contains(existing) ?? false);
```

the code

```
public void PrepareLinks()
{
    LinksAndFileNames.Clear();
    Links.Clear();

    GenerateRadarLinks();

    // Exclude links for files that already exist in the folder
    foreach (var existing in Directory.GetFiles(Folder, "*.png").Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension))
    {
        var link = Links.FirstOrDefault(linkItem => linkItem?.Contains(existing) ?? false);
        if (link != null)
        {
            Links.Remove(link);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you actually have a problem here: `Directory.GetFiles(Folder, "*.png").Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension))`  You are using `Select()` wrong here, this Select is a LINQ expression which is iterating over a string, or more specifically a collection of `char`.  try typing this in VS to see what I mean -> `@"C:\path\file.txt".Select(c => c == "f").ToList()` which will result in a `List<string>` with a single 'f' in the list.

Comment: @AdamVincent then using just a foreach cwithout the Select at all  is the solution in this case ?  foreach (var existing in Directory.GetFiles(Folder, "*.png"))
{
    var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(existing);
    var link = Links.FirstOrDefault(linkItem => linkItem?.Contains(fileName) ?? false);
    if (link != null)
    {
        Links.Remove(link);
    }
}

Comment: @AdamVincent `Directory.GetFiles` returns `string[]` so when you iterate that you get `string`, which can be passed to `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` and therefore the result is `IEnumerable<string>` not `IEnumerable<char>`. This is not the issue.

Answer (score -1):

`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` returns a `string?`. Such a value could contain a `null` (even though realistically it's not going to).

You could just say "ignore it" with the `!` postfix operator

```
var link = Links.FirstOrDefault(linkItem => linkItem?.Contains(existing!) ?? false);
```

Or test it

```
if (existing == null) continue;
var link = Links.FirstOrDefault(linkItem => linkItem?.Contains(existing) ?? false);
```

You can however improve the efficiency of your method with two things

- Use `EnumerateFiles` instead of `GetFiles`, as the latter returns an array.
- Get the index of the list match and remove at that match

---

```
foreach (var existing in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Folder, "*.png").Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension))
{
    if (existing == null) continue;
    var index = Links.FindIndex(linkItem => linkItem?.Contains(existing) ?? false);
    if (index != -1)
    {
        Links.RemoveAt(index);
    }
}
```

If you want to remove all possible matches, you can simply do

```
Links.RemoveAll(linkItem => linkItem?.Contains(existing) ?? false);
```